# Run asp.net 4.0 app under SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, .net-4.0

I have an asp.net 2.0 user control library that runs within a SharePoint site. We upgraded one of the assemblies that this application depends on to .net 4.0 so we were forced to update the website to an asp.net 4.0 site so that it could use that assembly. That caused us to run into this error:

Could not find permission set named 'ASP.Net'.

Which is documented here: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770151

and states:

"This error occurs because the ASP.NET 4 code access security (CAS) infrastructure looks for a permission set named ASP.Net. However, the partial trust configuration file that is referenced by WSS_Minimal does not contain any permission sets with that name."

Their proposed solution is don't attempt to use .net 4.0 which is not really an acceptable solution. So I'm trying to better understand what the actual problem. Our site is actually using a custom permission config based off of WSS_Minimal but it apparently includes the same reference. Can anyone tell me what file they are referring to when they say "the partial trust configuration file"? Where exactly does wss_Minimal reference this file? If the permission set named ASP.Net doesn't exist, I should be able to create my own permission set to take it's place. I'm not CAS expert but I haven't been able to find an ASP.Net permission set using the .net 2.0 configuration tool, and I'm not sure where it's being referenced in the wss_minimal config. Where is this ASP.Net permission set defined?

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint 2010 is based on ASP.NET 3.5 and SharePoint 2007 is based on ASP.NET 2.0. So I'm guessing that you cannot do this (base your site .NET on 4.0).

Comment: If this is really the case, what a freaking nightmare. This is another item to add to my laundry list of reasons to never use share point (unless it's basic document collaboration and nothing else).

Comment: There was a lot of SharePoint stuff that wasn't ready for the VS 2010/4.0 release date, for example: Workflow 4.0. Sites in SharePoint are based on the version I listed, so I don't think you can just go in and convert them. May be easier to version the library instead?

Comment: Thanks IrishChieftain. I guess that would make sense. For the sake of my curiosity and the thread, I'd still like to know the answers to the posed questions though. It seems like there should be some way of still accessing a .net 4 assembly from a sharepoint site...the only way I've thought of is exposing methods and types the assembly via a web/wcf service.

Comment: @chris: i think any product would have problems if you changed the reference assemblies that is running on.

Comment: @xr280xr, I think the security error message is neither here nor there. 4.0 assemblies are no supported. If there is not much 4.0-specific functionality, or other application dependencies, could you retain the 2.0 version?

Comment: @djeeg if IIS can host all of it at the same time share point should be able to.

Comment: @Chris SharePoint currently does not support 4.0: bit.ly/fjKZzO

Answer (score 0):

I have been running a 4.0 App in a virtual directory in a MOSS 2007 site.  I just installed Security Update for Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 (KB2687405) 32-Bit Edition and BAM got the same error on the 4.0 App.  Added

```
    <trust level="Full" legacyCasModel="true" />
```

to web.config in the virtual directory and all's well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Web.Config:

Set..

```
<trust level="WSS_Minimal"
```

As..

```
<trust level="Full"
```